# Flutter Google login callback url?

Tags: spring, flutter, spring-boot, oauth-2.0

I have an app in Angular and after Google/Facebook login its done a
callback call to my Spring Oauth app (I specify it on redirect_uri
property). Is there something similar with Flutter or do I have to do a
post myself to store authenticated user info on my backend?